# How to say the total amount?

Tags: numbers, speech, money

I'm not sure if the saying of the total amount USD 23,428.32 is correct below (esp. the 'cent' part after the dot):

> Say U.S. dollars twenty-three thousand four hundred and twenty-eight and thirty-two cents.

And if it is 23,428.00, do I say

> Say U.S. dollars twenty-three thousand four hundred and twenty-eight only.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write decimal values in words](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59586/how-to-write-decimal-values-in-words)

Comment: I guess the question mentioned above doesn't address the ".00" case.  Neither do [question #28545](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28545/how-can-i-write-out-1-5) and [question #10687](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10687/rule-for-adding-and-or-hyphens-between-numbers-that-are-spelled-out-fully-in-t) and [question #33381](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33381/how-to-write-numbers-in-words). Oh well.

Comment: Follow the International Organization for Standardization (ISO) standard ISO_4217 [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217]

Answer (score 3):

If I was saying them,
bearing in mind I am a native Brit:

> Twenty-three thousand, four hundred and twenty-eight dollars, and
>   thirty-two cents

(with that first 'and' being used in speech, but not in writing eg on a cheque, although interestingly in the UK you can use that first 'and')

and

> Twenty-three thousand, four hundred and twenty-eight dollars

Comment: Prescriptively (and on bank documents), the first 'and' should not be used; it should only be used as a separator between the dollars and the cents. In speech, it's hard to avoid the first 'and'.

Comment: Rory Alsop, in the UK, it's not just a case of you *can* use that first *and*. It is normal to use it.

Comment: Maybe I should strengthen the point, Tristan. I was aiming to point out the difference between the American way and ours.

Comment: Mitch, it would be enlightening if you would mention where in the world, your comment applies. In England and the rest of the UK, the first *and* is normal and therefore, should be used.

Comment: Rory Alsop, that would be helpful to non-native speakers.

Answer (score 3):

On a check – which is one of the few places where you see such numbers written out in their long form – you might see any of the following conventions used:

- *Twenty-three thousand four hundred twenty-eight dollars &
  thirty-two cents*
- *Twenty-three thousand four hundred twenty-eight dollars and 32
  cents*
- *Twenty-three thousand four hundred twenty-eight dollars and 32/100*

I don't believe too many people would use the top one, though – not when they were writing out the number in longhand – although you might see the number of cents spelled out on a computer-printed check.

In the case where the dollar amount is even, you might see:

- *Twenty-three thousand four hundred twenty-eight dollars and no cents*
- *Twenty-three thousand four hundred twenty-eight dollars and no/100*
- *Twenty-three thousand four hundred twenty-eight dollars & 0/100*
- *Twenty-three thousand four hundred twenty-eight dollars only*

I think the last one is relatively uncommon, although I've personally used it for decades.  (I first saw it as a teenager, thought it was a cool, quirky way to write checks in even amounts, and so I adopted the practice.)  Sometimes I'll even use the word *exactly*, when the dollar amount is more even:

- *Twenty-three thousand four hundred dollars exactly*

although I don't usually write checks in that large an amount.

Comment: I also often use `xx/100` for zero cents.

Comment: When speaking, I use *even*, like "that'll be 43 dollars *even*".

Answer (score 0):

In US English ***and*** is used only to separate Dollars and cents.

*101* is written *One hundred one* with no *and*.

*US$ 101.50* would be written as *US Dollar One hundred One and Fifty cents*

Where the amount is a whole number (no cents), it is terminated by the word *Only*:

*Dollars One hundred One only.*

Answer (score -1):

Probably your answer is true. But i can write USD 23,428.32 as " U. S. DOLLARS TWENTY-THREE THOUSAND FOUR HUNDRED TWENTY-EIGHT AND THIRTY-TWO HUNDREDTHS".

Comment: Nobody in the US uses "hundredths" to describe "cents" normally

Comment: @simchona: except on a check, where most would write 32/100 after the "...Twenty-Eight" (sorry, I couldn't write it in all CAPS, it was getting too loud in here)

Comment: @J.R. I know that write it in all CAPS, getting too loud in here. I write all in caps because to notify people. Don't be silly.

Comment: Yes, the comment was silly, but I don't see what's wrong with an occasional silly comment – not if it's only intended to amuse the community. After all, EL&U should be both interesting and fun. When I wrote my comment, the O.P. had written his question in ALL CAPS as well (it has since been edited), so essentially, most of the page looked like a lot of [yelling](http://kathrynvercillo.hubpages.com/hub/What-People-Think-When-You-Type-in-All-Caps) was going on. Note, too, the main part of my comment (the part _outside_ the parentheses) supports what you originally wrote. I meant no harm.